# How to get previous date period

Tags: javascript

I want to compare current 30 days period with previous 30 day period.

```
const period = 30;
const today = new Date();
const startOfCurrentPeriod = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-period));
const startOfPreviousPeriod = new Date(new Date().setDate(startOfCurrentPeriod.getDate()-period));


console.log(startOfCurrentPeriod, startOfPreviousPeriod);
```

Im expecting

```
2020-09-28T17:24:02.766Z
2020-08-29T17:24:02.766Z
```

But im getting

```
2020-09-28T17:24:02.766Z
2020-09-28T17:24:02.766Z
```

https://repl.it/repls/AptUnwittingSort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `getDate()` methode returns the day of month, not the amount of days (like `getTime()` does returns the amount milliseconds from epoch). so suppose you are on 30 November, and subtract it with 30 days, you get 2 October, and `getDate()` returns 2. You need to subtract it from the other date instead of the current date.

```
const period = 30;
const today = new Date();
const startOfCurrentPeriod = new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-period));
const startOfPreviousPeriod = new Date(new Date(startOfCurrentPeriod).setDate(startOfCurrentPeriod.getDate()-period));


console.log(startOfCurrentPeriod, startOfPreviousPeriod);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `setDate` modifies the date object:

```
const period = 30;
const today = new Date();
const startOfCurrentPeriod = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-period));
const startOfPreviousPeriod = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-period));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Johnny Mopp gave a working answer, I'll just explain what's happening in OP's sample.

```
const period = 30;
const today = new Date();
```

According to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), **`setDate()`** sets the **day** of the Date object **relative** to the beginning of the **currently set month**.

Today is **`October 28th`**.

Still according to the MDN webdocs, the following line gets a date two days **before the end of the previous month**, September here, since `28 - 30 = -2` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)), so **`September 28th`**:

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-period));
```

The day of the date of `startOfCurrentPeriod` is 28 as well as the `today` Date object. Since `setDate()` always works relatively to the beginning of the current month, the next line also ends up having a day value of `28 - 30 = -2`, so **`September 28th`**

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(startOfCurrentPeriod.getDate()-period));
```

Answer (score 0):

The **getTime** is my way to achieve the desired result.

```
const period = 30;
const today = new Date();
const startOfCurrentPeriod = new Date();
startOfCurrentPeriod.setDate(today.getDate()-period);
const startOfPreviousPeriod = new Date(startOfCurrentPeriod.getTime());
startOfPreviousPeriod.setDate(startOfCurrentPeriod.getDate()-period);

console.log(startOfCurrentPeriod);
console.log(startOfPreviousPeriod);
```

And the result is:

```
2020-09-28T17:44:48.507Z
2020-08-29T17:44:48.507Z
```